# How do I prevent a nodejs app from logging any client information

Tags: node.js

How would I prevent a nodejs app from logging any client IPs or user agent info. Basically, I don't want any record that my app was used by a client. I want to protect some of my users privacy by not even keeping a server log.

Is this possible in node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Node.js doesn't keep a server log by default.